# How to Find the maximum consecutive years for each ID using Scala / Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have certain ID's for each row with the respective years of operation:

Example:

```
ID   YEAR

A1   1999
A2   2000
A1   2000
B1   1998
A1   2002
```

Now, I need to Identify the No. of consecutive years for each ID 
Result,

```
A1 : 2  because[1999, 2000 ]
```

etc .,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a `Spark` solution, I would choose a `DataFrame`. It gets messy, but it's an interesting problem:

```
val testDf = Seq(
  ("A1", 1999),
  ("A2", 2000),
  ("A1", 2000),
  ("A1", 1998),
  ("A1", 2002),
  ("B1", 1998)
).toDF("ID", "YEAR")
```

Then I would perform a self-join (the first of two, actually):

```
val selfJoined = testDf.orderBy($"YEAR").join(
  testDf.orderBy($"YEAR").toDF("R_ID", "R_YEAR"),
  $"R_ID" === $"ID" && $"YEAR" === ($"R_YEAR" - 1),
  "full_outer"
).filter($"ID".isNull || $"R_ID".isNull)

selfJoined.show
+----+----+----+------+
|  ID|YEAR|R_ID|R_YEAR|
+----+----+----+------+
|null|null|  A2|  2000|
|  A2|2000|null|  null|
|null|null|  B1|  1998|
|  B1|1998|null|  null|
|null|null|  A1|  1998|
|  A1|2000|null|  null|
|null|null|  A1|  2002|
|  A1|2002|null|  null|
+----+----+----+------+
```

As you can see from the above, we now have the start and end dates for contiguous runs of years. `R_YEAR`, when not `null`, contains the start of a "run" of consecutive years. The very next line, the `YEAR` is the end of that run of years. If I were more adept at `Window` features, I might use `lag` to stitch together the records, but I'm not so I won't. I'll do another self-join, then a `groupBy`, then some math in a `select`, then another `groupBy`:

```
selfJoined.filter($"ID".isNull).as("a").join(
  selfJoined.filter($"R_ID".isNull).as("b"),
  $"a.R_ID" === $"b.ID" && $"a.R_YEAR" <= $"b.YEAR"
).groupBy($"a.R_ID", $"a.R_YEAR").agg(min($"b.YEAR") as "last_YEAR")
 .select($"R_ID" as "ID", $"last_YEAR" - $"R_YEAR" + 1 as "inarow")
 .groupBy($"ID").agg(max($"inarow") as "MAX").show
+---+---+
| ID|MAX|
+---+---+
| B1|  1|
| A1|  3|
| A2|  1|
+---+---+
```

Wheee!

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed explanation with steps, Really appreciate the solution!. But, My desired output should have A1 -> 2 since A1 has 1999, 2000, 2002 (Here 2002 is not consecutive years.)

Comment: Look at my data, it is different. I added another year for A1 for a better yest case.

Comment: David Griffin Can you kindly explain the logic part, multiple self joins and The Arithmetic behind it. Tired my best to grasp it looks tedious and want to confirm if my interpretation is right.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to bother with Spark SQL (in my opinion, it's overkill for the task), you can simply use *groupByKey* (while number of possible years per id is reasonable)

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A1", 1999),
  ("A2", 2000),
  ("A1", 2000),
  ("A1", 1998),
  ("A1", 2002),
  ("B1", 1998)
))

def findMaxRange(l: Iterable[Int]) = {
  val ranges = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int](1)
  l.toSeq.sorted.distinct.sliding(2).foreach { case y1 :: tail =>
    if (tail.nonEmpty) {
      val y2 = tail.head
      if (y2 - y1 == 1)  ranges(ranges.size - 1) +=  1
      else ranges += 1
    }
  }
  ranges.max
}

rdd1.groupByKey.map(r => (r._1, findMaxRange(r._2))).collect()

res7: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((A1,3), (A2,1), (B1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines:

```
scala> case class DataRow(id: String, year: Int)
defined class DataRow
scala> val data = Seq(
           DataRow("A1", 1999),
           DataRow("A2", 2000),
           DataRow("A1", 2000),
           DataRow("B1", 1998),
           DataRow("A1", 2002)
         )
data: Seq[DataRow] = List(DataRow("A1", 1999), DataRow("A2", 2000), DataRow("A1", 2000), DataRow("B1", 1998), DataRow("A1", 2002))
scala> data.groupBy(_.id).mapValues { rows =>
           val years = rows.map(_.year)
           val firstYear = years.head
           years.zipWithIndex.takeWhile { case (y, i) => y == firstYear + i }.size
         }
res1: Map[String, Int] = Map("B1" -> 1, "A2" -> 1, "A1" -> 2)
```

This computes the maximum number of consecutive years for each ID, assuming the first year it sees is the earliest date of the strike. Insert `.sorted` in the `val years` line is this is not the case.

Comment: That doesn't use `Spark`.